# Change Google Chart slider width through CSS class (CSS Injection on Google Chart)

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Hi I am using Google Charts as the analysis of some data. However I am stucked on customizing charts and controls using css. I tried to use ui.cssclass but no luck...

```
rangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
            'containerId': 'slider' + num,
            'options': {
                'minValue': 1,
                'maxValue': 10,
                'filterColumnLabel': Count
            },
            'ui': {
                'cssClass': 'sliderClass'
            }
        });
```

My class 'sliderClass' contains...

```
.sliderClass
{
width:50px;
}
```

Do I use it in the right way, where i declare a class called 'sliderClass' at the main css? 
However the range slider does not change its width based on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is a bit tricky, since we don't expose anything to set the width of the control. What you actually need to set the width of is the element with the class 'google-visualization-controls-slider-horizontal'. I believe if you change your CSS to

```
.sliderClass .google-visualization-controls-slider-horizontal {
  width:50px;
}
```

then it should work.

Comment: You may also want to add this: .sliderClass .google-visualization-controls-rangefilter { white-space: nowrap }

Comment: Sergey or @dlaliberte -- how do you get a list of these hidden elements? Do you just check firebug after generating the HTML to see what it ends up being called?

Comment: Inspecting the HTML is how I found the class names, and since these are otherwise undocumented, that is your only option at this time.